# error: "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem.PropertySystemException Unable to get writable property store for this property."

Tags: c#, .net, xlsx

I have created dotnet application which is updating metadata (e.g. "Title" property) of XLSX file.

I am using `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell` library in my application...which is perfectly updating metadata of that file on development environment.

But on production server that application is not working.

It is giving error like.....

> Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem.PropertySystemException
>   (0x80004005): Unable to get writable property store for this property.

Development and Production environment is having same OS installed. Visual Studio and office installed on delvelopment environment. But not on production environment.

Does any one have idea on this?

Comment: The Windows api codepack was discontinued quite a while ago.  I suspect that was because they had trouble supporting programmers with hard-to-diagnose mishaps.  Like this one, it gives very little guidance towards the underlying issue.  Using try/catch to swallow any exception is important.  It is likely to fail, either because the file format does not support adding metadata, the machine doesn't have a PropertyHandler component installed that supports the file format or because your app does not have write permission to the file.  Most obvious reason is the machine not having Office installed

Comment: That is what we are trying to implement.. we donot want any dependency on microsoft office for reading and writing the excel files... does anyone have any solution as to how this error could be solved ?

Comment: maybe your application  doesn't have permission to read this file or the file is opened